# Does marking a method async when it contains only synchronous calls actually causes async execution?

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await

I have following method:

```
public async Task M1()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        await M2();
    }
}

public async Task M2()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        //synchronous operations
    }
}
```

Will actually marking `M2` as async despite it has only sync operations inside will make any difference regarding a way it's being executed?

Comment: It won't make it run on another thread or anything -- if it just contains synchronous code, it will run the same as if it wasn't marked `async`. The only difference is if it throws an exception: `async` methods will catch the exception and wrap it up inside the `Task` that they return.

Comment: `async` makes .net create a finite state machine; if there are synchronous operations only, the state machine will be degenerated one (synchronous execution with results wrapped into `Task`, no extra threads etc.) that's why `async` is redundant.

Comment: So, you're getting a warning from the compiler telling you that the code will only run synchronously but you somehow think it's lying to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, moreover everything before first `await` on "truly async" function will be executed synchronously. Check out the next code:

```
var task = M1();
Console.WriteLine("before outer await");
await task;
Console.WriteLine("after outer await");

async Task M1()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("before await M2");
        await M2();
        Console.WriteLine("after await M2");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("before await");
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine("after await");
}

async Task M2()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

Which will produce output like:

```
before await M2
// ... numbers
after await M2 
before await M2
// ... numbers
after await M2
before await
before outer await
after await
after outer await
```

And then compare output with the following `M2` version:

```
async Task M2()
{
    await Task.Delay(100);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

Which will result in `before outer await` written earlier (somewhere after first `"before await M2"`).

Some potentially useful links:

- [Asynchronous Programming in .NET - Introduction, Misconceptions, and Problems](https://wapplegate.com/asynchronous-programming/)
- [Asynchronous programming doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/async-scenarios)
- [Task asynchronous programming model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/task-asynchronous-programming-model)
- [How Async/Await Really Works in C#](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/how-async-await-really-works/) - if you want to dive deeper
- [Dissecting the async methods in C#](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/dissecting-the-async-methods-in-c/) - if you want to dive deeper

Comment: Not necessary at *first await*, afaik. It is said - at first await that is **source of asynchronousy**. `Task.Delay` belongs to that category.

Comment: @Ryan yes, exactly. That is what the _"truly async"_ remark meant.

Answer (score 0):

If a function only contains synchronous operations and doesn't truly require asynchronous behavior, there's generally no real benefit to marking it as async. It's usually better to reserve async for functions that perform I/O-bound or otherwise asynchronous operations, where the non-blocking behavior would provide a genuine advantage.